# Selenium drag frame

Tags: selenium, frames

Here is a webpage with three frames : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols .
There is an anchor with id="dragbar" and cursor : col-resize attribute and it appears it is draggable by clicking and holding onto it . 
Question :
How would I automate this drag in Selenium ?

Comment: Can you give a complete minimal example where the problem occurs so that other people can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Well , I guess nobody knows what I am talking about then . I will post a picture of the webpage I guess later but not sure that will help either .

Comment: Here is a better example : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols ... So from what I see there is an anchor with id="dragbar" and it is being dragged by some javascript ?

Comment: I rewrote my question . Hope that helps .